# replaceWith on XML problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, replacewith

After examining the jQuery source, I see that the problem I am having is because `replaceWith` calls `html` which does not exist for XML documents. Is `replaceWith` not supposed to work on XML documents?

I have found this admittedly simple workaround, in case anybody needs it in the future, that will accomplish what I'm trying to do:

```
xml.find('b').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($('<c>yo</c>')) // this way you can custom taylor the XML based on each node's attributes and such
});
```

But I would still like to know why the easy way doesn't work.

---

I don't know much about jQuery, but shouldn't this work?

```
xml = $.parseXML('<a><b>hey</b></a>')
$(xml).find('b').replaceWith('<c>yo</c>')
```

Instead of `xml` representing `<a><c>yo</c></a>` it fails and represents `<a></a>`. Did I do something wrong? I am using jQuery 1.6.2.

*Edit:*

As a side note, if I try to use the function version of `replaceWith`, like so:

```
$(xml).find('b').replaceWith(function() {
    return '<c>yo</c>' // doesn't matter what I return here
})
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
```

*Edit 2:*

`replaceAll` works however, but I need to use the function version so I can't settle for this:

```
$('<c>yo</c>').replaceAll($(xml).find('b')) // works
```

*Edit 3:*

This also works:

```
xml.find('b').replaceWith($('<c>yo</c>')) // but not with the $() around the argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like either a design limitation with `replaceWith()` or a bug.

When I run:

```
$(xml).find('b').replaceWith(function() {
    return '<c>yo</c>';
})
```

I get a `"this[0].innerHTML is undefined"` exception.  [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvt2y/).

Drilling into `xml`, the `b` node doesn't have an innerHTML member -- which makes a little sense, since it's not HTML. ;)

So, it's looking like `replaceWith()` may not always play nice with XML.  [Consider reporting a bug](http://docs.jquery.com/How_to_Report_Bugs).

Comment: Would you consider this worth reporting?

Comment: @Seth: Sure, why not? The worst that can happen is that you'll get a "won't fix" and at least the issue will be documented.

Comment: Yes.  It doesn't work as reasonable people would expect, or as the documentation implies.  Just search for prior bugs before posting (I did a *quick* search and didn't see anything).

Comment: @mu is too short:  No the worst that could happen is... "You are a blithering idiot; here's proof." :)  I've been called worse.

Answer (score 0):

yes. this is old bug and it still exists. you can workaround it:

```
$.ajax
  dataType: "xml"
  ...
  success:  (data) ->
    $(data).find("section").each ->
      ugly_but_working_clone = $($(".existing_dom_element").append(this).html())
```