# jQuery XML parsing and replace tags

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing, parsexml

I needed to replace then node having field name with the xml node.

I tried with `replaceWith` which did not parse properly.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632482/replacewith-on-xml-problem) I tried to create a workaround to replace xml tag

```
   $.fn.replaceWithXML = function replaceWithXML(ele) {
        var xml = this.html();
        return $('<dummy />').append($(ele).append(xml)).html();
    }
```

It was not working with all the xml tags properly.

```
 xml = '<field><col>Col1</col></field>'
 xml = $.parseXML(xml);
```

Replacing the "field" with "column" yields unexpected output ''

Neither this works

```
var xml_node = '<column></column>';
$(root).append(xml_node,{html: $(xml ).find('field').html()});
```

Nor this works

```
$(root).append($(xml_node).append($(xml ).find('field').html()));
```

Comment: Type Error! I have field tag. I wrongly typed "Filed"

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your xml attempt (filed)

```
xml = '<field><col>Col1</col></filed>'
```

should be (field)

```
xml = '<field><col>Col1</col></field>'
```

Now that you edited this into your question, using `find` works to locate the element. The next problem is now that you are using `.innerHTML` on a jquery object, when you should use `.html()`

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/8ULMC/)***

```
var xml = '<field><col>Col1</col></field>';
xml = $.parseXML(xml);
console.log(xml);
alert($(xml).find("col").html());
```

Comment: I wanted to replace the tag after getting the content

Comment: And also some of the jquery function does not support other than native HTML tags is used.